# PyMySQL handling None in select statements

Tags: python, pymysql

What is the best way to handle None values in a select statement in PyMySQL. For example let's say I want to generate the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = %s
AND address = %s
AND city = %s
AND phone = %s
```

However, phone can be None in which case the statement would need to be like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = %s
AND address = %s
AND city = %s
AND phone IS NULL
```

or the following would also be acceptable:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE name = %s
AND address = %s
AND city = %s
```

The actual queries are much more complex so I'm looking for a general solution. In PHP I can normally just search using an associative array and then filter out the empty values.

Comment: If it helps, in the Python DB API, `SQL NULL values are represented by the Python None singleton on input and output.`

Comment: That part is clear, the issue is in MySQL you don't write "ITEM = NULL" but rather "ITEM IS NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

`"SELECT * FROM table WHERE "+("phone = %s" if phone else "phone is NULL")`

and continuing that pattern.